# Access VBA set variable to string "Yes" not -1

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am using Access to import information from Excel and then cycle through the data. I do not have control of the information that is in the Excel document. The Excel document is used for performing audits and I am doing reporting on the results. Recently a change was made so that some of the answers are no longer Yes/No. Answer may be "No - Document missing". I created a table that stores Yes/No/NA responses to be able to capture these changes however I now have stumbled upon an issue.

```
yText = Nz(Dlookup("yText","tblQuestions","Group = '" & group & "' AND Question = " & qID), "Yes")
```

The yText is used in a dynamic SQL string so because that value stored in the field will be 'Yes' as a string I need yText to equal 'Yes' but instead VBA changes yText = -1. The same issue occurs with nText = 'No'. Is there any way to prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Format within DlookUp:

```
Format(yText,"Yes/No")

Dlookup("Format(yText,'Yes/No')","tblQuestions","Group = '" _
 & group & "' AND Question = " & qID)
```

Comment: The Format() will wrap the NZ(Dlookup()) to convert what is returned. Thanks for the quick response. Figured it was simple.

Comment: No it won't :) Your Nz returns a string for nulls.

Comment: If the field is Null then I want 'Yes', but is the field has 'Yes' in it I need the 'Yes' string. In both cases VBA will change to -1 so the Format has to wrap the return to capture both instances.

Comment: You need to change Nz from "Yes" to -1, is that what you are saying?

Comment: Otherwise just wrap the DlookUp or the field, not the Nz.